# How to set limit for recyclerView data, while its in reverse in direction, and i have to get the current data only? (Android Java)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i have history record of transaction which i'm getting from the api, these records are more than 50. when i show them in RecyclerView and use

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(RedemptionHistoryActivity.this);
                                linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
                                linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

now i got current one at the top, but how could i limit these records to only show 10 records in RecyclerView, because when i set limit to 10 in Adapter it show 10 records but starting 10 records not the current one.
please help me out that how can i get the current 10 records in Android Java.

```
historyAdapter = new HistoryAdapter(RedemptionHistoryActivity.this, historyModelArrayList);
                                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(RedemptionHistoryActivity.this);
                                linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
                                linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
                                rv_history.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                                rv_history.setAdapter(historyAdapter);
                                historyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```